# Getting the please ensure the component is wrapped in a provider even after wrapping it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, react-redux

I am using nextjs along with react redux.

I am getting this error:

> Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a `<Provider>`.

I have tried everything and have also wrapped it in a provider yet the error still persists.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { authActions } from '../store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from '../store';

export default function Signup(props) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        name: "", email: "", password: ""
    });

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setInputs((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }))
    }

    const sendRequest = async (type = "signup") => {
        const res = await axios.post(`https://blog-app-23.onrender.com/api/user/${type}`, {
            name: inputs.name,
            email: inputs.email,
            password: inputs.password
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
        const data = await res.data;
        return data;
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(inputs);
        sendRequest("signup")
            .then((data) => localStorage.setItem("userId", data.user._id))
            .then(() => dispatch(authActions.login()))
            .then(() => router.push("/courses"))
    }
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <section>
                <div className='h-[100vh] flex items-center'>
                    <ReactNebula className="nebula" config={{ astres: smallSolarSystem }} />
                    <div className='w-1/2 h-[30rem]'><ComputersCanvas /></div>
                    <div className='w-1/2 h-[10rem] stu flex items-center'>
                        <div className='h-[30rem] w-[29rem] rounded-3xl bg-white stu flex mx-auto p-6 flex-col'>
                            <h1 className='text-2xl font-semibold'>Sign Up</h1>
                            <div className='mt-5 flex flex-col'>
                                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                    <input name="name" onChange={handleChange} value={inputs.name} placeholder='name' className="py-2 my-3 px-5 ml-2 rounded-md bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 flex-grow mr-4" />
                                    <input name="email" onChange={handleChange} value={inputs.email} type={'email'} placeholder='email' className="py-2 my-3 px-5 ml-2 rounded-md bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 flex-grow mr-4" />
                                    <input name="password" onChange={handleChange} value={inputs.password} type={'password'} placeholder='password' className="py-2 my-3 px-5 ml-2 rounded-md bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 flex-grow mr-4" />
                                    <button type={"submit"} className=' mt-7 started text-white py-3 px-5 text-md rounded-2xl bg-red-500' >Sign Up</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

I tried everything and the code didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `useDispatch()` outside of `<Provider>`, because  `<Provider>` is currently contained inside `<Signup>`'s markup.

Move `Signup`'s contents inside a separate component (named `WithProvider` below) ***<sup>1</sup>***:

```js
// imports...

export default function Signup(props) {
  return (
    <Provider store="store">
      <WithProvider {...props} />
    </Provider>
  )
}
function WithProvider(props) {
  // you can `useDispatch()` here because it's inside `<Provider>`
}
```

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - You can name it `WithStore` or whatever else you want; it's a local function. The default export is still `<Signup>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Signup` component can't access any redux context since it's the component rendering the redux context. Promote `Provider` higher in the ReactTree than any component that needs to access the context it provides. In this case you can simply wrap `Signup` in the `Provider` component and it can use the `useDispatch` hook.

Example:

```
<Provider store={store}> // <-- provides redux context to sub-ReactTree
  ...
  <Signup />
  ...
</Provider>
```

```
export default function Signup(props) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); // <-- can access redux context now

  ...

  return (
    <section>
      ...
    </section>
  );
}
```